# id_rsa invalid format in Dockerfile when using Makefile

Tags: docker, github, makefile, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I am attempting to pass an SSH key into a Dockerfile so I can pull down private repos from Git.

It works when I use this on the command line

```
export SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY  --tag image:latest .
```

Below is a snippet of my Dockerfile

```
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git && apt-get install -y nano && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip python3.7-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && umask 0077 && echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/ \
    && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

However when I try and run it from a makefile like so

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(shell cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)


build-image:
    docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" --tag image:latest -f ./docker/Dockerfile .
```

I get the error

> Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format

Am I doing anything obviously wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you know why you get `invalid format`. I just tried to reproduce and got `invalid format` using the direct `docker build` also.

Comment: I missed some quotes around the SSH var in the dockerfile, example should work with direct docker build now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(shell cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)`. Make converts newlines from [shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) outputs to spaces. Use

```bash
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid running either `git` or `ssh` commands in a Dockerfile.  Since you already have a Makefile, it's very straightforward to clone the repository in the host build environment:

```make
# (not .PHONY, this actually creates the file)
some_dependency/some_file:
        git clone git@github.com:some_organization/some_dependency

build-image: some_dependency/some_file
        docker build --tag image:latest -f ./docker/Dockerfile .
```

You should avoid running `ssh` because it's basically impossible to securely manage the private keys.  In your example, anyone who gets a copy of your image can trivially

```
docker run --rm image:latest cat .ssh/id_rsa
```

and now your private key is compromised.

The argument against `git clone` in a Dockerfile is a little more subtle.  Docker's layer caching means that it will try to avoid re-running a command it's already run.  That means if you've built this image on this host previously, re-running `docker build` will use the same checkout it had before; it will not repeat a `git clone` and you'll be stuck on an old version.  This also means that building the same image on different hosts can get different results, depending on the first time the image got built.

In the context of a private repository that your colleagues are working on, also consider the cases where you need to build a test image against a pull request or another branch, or where you actually need to test a local change against that dependency.  `git clone` in the Dockerfile working specifically on `master` will get in your way here; cloning the repository on the host readily allows both of these cases.